# Visual Studio 2017 and npm. Exclamation mark near the npm references in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc

What does it mean:

[image]

"Resotore Packages.." doesn't help. Still exclamation, still empty.

I should say that npm from console works well: all packages are in place. packages.json and packages.lock are ok.

How Visual Studio determine the "problem"? which file it uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wipe out `folder` for `npm`, probably hidden `node_modules` in your `asp.net core project`

from command line use `npm init` or PMC (from within VS).

If you are absolutely sure the `package.json` is fine then anything that was off will now get restored.  Any bangout that occurs now is a result of either a bad restore from npm (automagic btw, on change).  Or your `package.json` has something missing like a `,` (a comma).

## -mv

Comment: ok I will try `npm init`. this is good advice. I thin that package.json is ok since `npm install` works well. node_modules is in place. all modules are ok - since webpack works well. just this exclamation bother me (and my clients).

Comment: you should be able to see the errors in console log for NPM in VS

Comment: 'npm init' fix this. its strange. npm was setuped for this foler - npm install was working. black magic.